# Express endpoint works in Postman but not in my app

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express

I am working on an application with both a front-end and a back-end. The front uses Angular, and the back Node.js (Express). They communicate with a Rest API.

When I request this endpoint with Postman ou directly with my web browser, it works and I get the right result.

However, when I am requesting it since one component of my app, it just doesn't work.

The call is here

```
console.log("Call GETSAVE");
this.rest.getSave(type, file).subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
});
```

Then, in my service

```
getSave(type: enumType, path: string) {
    console.log(this.url + 'saves/' + type + path);
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'saves/' + type + path);
}
```

with HTTP being an instance of HttpClient (injected in the constructor).

All endpoints of this service work and I call them in the same way as above, but for this endpoint, the subscribe just doesn't work. I never enter the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, and it's quite simple.

By default, HTTPClient will parse data as a JSON. In my case, it was not a JSON but a text.
In consequence, there was an error because it couldn't parse the text as a JSON.

To fix this issue, you need to add a parameter in the request with a "responseType".

In my case :

```
getSave(type: enumType, path: string) {
    console.log(this.url + 'saves/' + type + path);
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'saves/' + type + path, {
      'responseType':'text'
    });
}
```